# Define Python class in separate file

Tags: python-3.x, oop, instance-variables, abstraction

```
# File 1
me = MongoEngine(app) # I want to use my instance of MongoEngine to define new classes like the example in File 2

# File 2
class Book(me.Document):
    title = StringField(null=False, unique=True)
    year_published = IntField(null=True)
```

How can i pass the instance `me.Document` as an Object definition when creating my new classes in a new file. It works if i put them in the same file?

Comment: Why don't you just import `File 2`.

Comment: What have you tried already? `me` is in this case no different from any other Python object that you can import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the answer choosen as answer is not fully correct.

**It seems that `File1.py` is your main script which is executed**, 
and `File2.py` is a module which contains a `class` you wish to use in `File1.py`

Also based on a [previous question of the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48738490/set-variable-as-type-of-class) I would like to suggest the following structure:

File1.py and File2.py are located in the same direcory

**File1.py**

```
import MongoEngine
from File2 import Book

me = MongoEngine(app)

# according to the documentation
# you do need to pass args/values in the following line
my_book = Book(me.Document(*args, **values))
# then do something with my_book
# which is now an instance of the File2.py class Book
```

**File2.py**

```
import MongoEngine

class Book(MongoEngine.Document):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Book, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # you can add additional code here if needed

    def my_additional_function(self):
        #do something
        return True
```

Comment: The super class is actually what i was looking for to avoid circular references!

Answer (score 2):

In `File 2` perform import of the `me` object:

```
from file1 import me


class Book(me.Document):
    pass
    # ...
```

Comment: This works great but if i then want to use the `Book` class in File1, I run into a circular reference. File 1 in this example is my `main.py`?

Comment: This has less to do with passing Python variables and more to do with the structure of your application. Apply standard circular resolution methods, for example import file2 at function level, or better yet remove implementation that depends upon `file2.py` from `file1.py` into a separate implementation file, thus breaking the circular dependency.

Comment: Also, you can simply avoid the `from x import y` construct to resolve circular imports automatically. This is a recommended answer on how Python imports work and how `import` differs from `from`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: it seems to me that file1 is the script which is executed, hence I would not import file1 into file2, I would do it the opposite way. This also explains the  circular reference problem. No need for circular references/imports

Answer (score 1):

Just like any Python object in a file, `me` can be imported. You can do it like so:

```
import file1
class Book(file1.me.Document):
    #Do what you want here!
```

Hope I have helped!